# Unity Gwibber lens doesn't work 12.10

Tags: unity, 12.10, lenses, gwibber

Is there something Specific I am needing to do to get the unity Gwibber/Social lens to work.

I have gone into system settings and added google account, twitter account and facebook account. When I go to the lens however nothing is displayed at all its blank. I search any term including my name and it states nothing to display. So it remains blank.

If I start gwibber itself it has found and does see my accounts new messages and posts.

Any hints on what to try?

Comment: I think its a bug. Try searching for it in launchpad. if not there. Report it

Comment: @Suhaib I saw the webupd8 teams youtube video and it is working for them. If I can obtain some useful info as to why not working I will report as a bug

Comment: @Sayth Did you disable the Amazon shopping results via privacy. This would also disable all lenses that use Online information.

Comment: cgubuntu1204 yes I did. Ah thanks. That should probably be an answer

Comment: @cgubuntu1204 Thanks, That's the correct answer.

Comment: Glad it worked. I added my suggestion as an answer so that anybody searching for this topic can have an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you have disabled `Amazon shopping results` via `Privacy settings`. Doing so would also disable any lenses that use internet results, such as `Gwibber`. Re enable `Include online search results`, to get the `Gwibber lens` back.

If you would like to disable Amazon Online results, open the terminal and run this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-lens-shopping
```

This is for 64bit OS.

For 32bit OS, run this instead:

```
unity-lens-shopping:i386
```

Alternatively, you can search for these packages in the `Software Centre` and remove them manually.